# How to get multiple enemies to cede provinces?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I'm playing as Ottomans.
I'm not in any coalition or alliances, but I have vassals.
I'm the target of a coalition of Venice, Poland, Bosnia, Persia, Ethiopia, Oman.
I have fabricated at least 1 claim per each of those counties.
I declare war with conquest war goal.
Even if I occupy every enemy province I have claims on, in the peace treaty I can only demand provinces from the one country I declared war on.
They entered the coalition at different times so the truce prevents them from fighting me all at once.
If I declared war on Oman, then Persia and Venice would come to Oman's aid, but Poland, Bosnia, and Ethiopia cannot help Oman because of their truce with me.
I thought I would demand few provinces from Oman, few from Persia, one from Venice, all occupied by me, but in the treaty screen I can only demand from Oman.

and this is odd, because few decades ago, when the coalition members were Mamelukes, Oman, Qara, Georgia, and I had no vassals but I had allies in Tripoli, I could demand provinces from numerous enemies at once. Didn't matter who I declared war on.

Comment: Can you negotiate a separate peace with Persia and Venice to demand the provinces you occupied from their lands?

Comment: @3ventic no I cannot. They're in a coalition not an alliance and this prevents me from separate peace.

Comment: Ah, right. I forgot coalitions prevent separate peace.

Answer (score 3):

Coalitions are an 'anti-blob' measure Paradox added to slow down expansion. Thus, members of the coalition (outside the target of the attack) are not part of the peace negotiation deals.

If in another war you could demand provinces from different countries, they probably were just allies (or cascade allies), but not there because of being in a coalition.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do this when fighting against coalitions. The only way I can think of to get around coalitions is, declaring war to one of the allies of the country you want to get a province from, instead of the country itself. i.e. declare war on one of the allies of Oman, and Oman will also join the war but other coalition members like Persia or Venice won't. You can try the same thing by declaring war on their allies also to fight several wars instead of having a big war against coalition countries.

But be careful about strong allies and propagating war leadership. You can end up fighting with big countries like France, Spain, Poland etc. which has nothing to do with the small country you want to fight against just because they are allied with an ally of the country you declared war on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could have taken provinces from each enemy if you were defending against a coalition, but it seems you're out of luck you're the attacker.